# Kendo Grid - how to dynamically translate top action buttons?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, translation

i would like to dynamically translate button below kendo grind (see image below).

[image]

And if somebody know how how to translate text for "Drag and drop"..i will be ver glad

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
I tried to do this, but this is not working:

```
toolbar: [
                { template: kendo.template($("#preparedViewsToolbar").html()) },
                { name: "create" },
                { name: "save" },
                { name: "cancel" }
            ],
            messages: {
                commands: {
                    cancel: "My Cancel changes",
                    canceledit: "My Cancel"
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using the latest version of Kendo UI this is pretty easy. Just need to define the messages in an array as in the Grid definition as:

```
messages: {
    commands: {
        cancel: "My Cancel changes",
        canceledit: "My Cancel",
        create: "My Add new record",
        destroy: "My Delete",
        edit: "My Edit",
        save: "My Save changes",
        select: "My Select",
        update: "My Update"
    }
}
```

Documentation in [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-messages)

For Groupable message, you should do:

```
groupable : {
    messages: {
        empty : "My Drag a column header and drop it here to group by that column"
    }
},
```

Documentation in [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-groupable.messages.empty)

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hb4yhco3/

**EDIT**: For older versions of Kendo UI as 2014.1.528, you should use the following approach:

```
toolbar   : [
    { template: kendo.template($("#preparedViewsToolbar").html()) },
    { name: "create", text : "My Add new record" }, 
    { name: "save", text: "My Save changes" },
    { name: "cancel", text: "My Cancel changes" }       
],
```

The previous JSFiddle example modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hb4yhco3/3/

Comment: Thanks for help, unfortunately it works only on groupable messages. For commands messages no.

Kendo version is 2014.1.528 

What should be wrong?

I updated my question for code example..

Comment: The problem is the version of KendoUI that you are using. The same JSFiddle that is in my answer with the version of KendoUI that you use (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hb4yhco3/2/) doesn't work. Can you update it?

Comment: The problem is the version of KendoUI that you are using. The same JSFiddle that is in my answer with the version of KendoUI that you use (jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hb4yhco3/2) doesn't work. Can you update it? If not, check **EDIT** on my answer.